# How can I setup a server to run my python code and return a value to the user?

Tags: python, apache, amazon-ec2, server

I have a python process/code configured on an AWS EC2 Linux server. The user inputs a string and it returns a string. Between the libraries and files required it is >1gb so I can't try Lambda or Beanstalk.

How would I go about setting up the server so someone could just send it their string and receive the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask for web application framework. 
https://github.com/pallets/flask

You can use gunicorn for web server.
https://gunicorn.org/